# Telerik GanttView Timeline GUI - modification

Tags: user-interface, telerik, gantt-chart

i want to change the behavior of my `Telerik GanttView TimeLineContainer`. The problem is, when i load data into GanttView with long duration (years) the TimeLine scales very bad. That means that it zooms in and not like I would have to zoom out. 
So in best case I would like to have the TimeLine scrollbar so that the user can adjust the size on runtime.

So far I tried this, but it doesnt scales right.

```
        this.radGanttView.GanttViewElement.GraphicalViewElement.TimelineContainer.StretchHorizontally = false;
        this.radGanttView.GanttViewElement.GraphicalViewElement.TimelineContainer.AutoSizeMode = Telerik.WinControls.RadAutoSizeMode.FitToAvailableSize;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a `RadTrackBar`:

```
    private void radTrackBar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int zoomfaktor = 10;
        double value = 51 + zoomfaktor * Math.Pow(this.radTrackBarZoom.Value, 2d);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", this.radTrackBarZoom.Value, value));
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0, (int)value, 0); this.radGanttView.GanttViewElement.GraphicalViewElement.OnePixelTime = time;
        this.radGanttView.GanttViewElement.GraphicalViewElement.OnePixelTime = time;
    }
```